# Script not working on Internet Explorer only?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have function like this in my header

```
function bingframe() {

var iframe = document.getElementById('bframe');
iframe.src = 'http://www.bing.com/search?q=' + document.searchForm.search.value.replace(/ /g,'+') + '&go=&form=QBLH&filt=all&qs=n&sk=';

}
```

So now when i call this function it responds in Google Chrome,Firefox and the modern browsers but not Internet explorer.

Can any of you modify the code accordingly ?

Thanking You.

Comment: which version of IE are you using?  IE6, IE7, IE8 or IE9 beta...  They all are different.  IE8 and IE9 beta are the closest to FF, and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me - IE8

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
<script>
function bingframe(theForm) {
  var iframe = document.getElementById('bframe');
  var url = 'http://www.bing.com/search?q=' + escape(theForm.search.value).replace(/ /g,'+') + '&go=&form=QBLH&filt=all&qs=n&sk=';
  iframe.src = url; 
  return false
}
window.onload=function() {
  document.forms[0].search.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="searchForm" onSubmit="return bingframe(this)">
<input type="text" name="search" value="" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
<iframe id="bframe" src="about:blank" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

however so does this - no script necessary:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
window.onload=function() {
  document.forms[0].q.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="searchForm" action="http://www.bing.com/search" target="bframe">
<input type="text" name="q" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="go" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="QBLH" />
<input type="hidden" name="filt" value="all" />
<input type="hidden" name="qs" value="n" />
<input type="hidden" name="sk" value="" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
<iframe name="bframe" src="about:blank" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```